# Resizing divs within a carousel with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, image-resizing

I am currently working on creating a pure jQuery carousel with the use of no plugins.

I have been told that adding a smart resize jQuery event handler is a really good way to do it. However, I just don't know how I would go about integrating it into the plugin that I am creating.

It is currently using the $(window).width method to determine the size of the li (picture_slide) and due to there being 3 images the ul (.slider) width is $(window).width * 3.

However any time I try to resize it the images are fitting to the screen, however the animation does not seem to be working.

Here is the plugin I have created that works but doesn't resize

```
;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
"use strict";
var pluginName = "chrisCarousel",
    defaults = {
        rotationSpeed: 1000,
        screenTime: 1000
    };

function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend(defaults, {}, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
}

$.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
    init: function () {
        this.myCarousel();
    },

    myCarousel: function () {
     var y = $(window).width();

        var t = setInterval(function () {
            $("#my_carousel ul").animate({marginLeft: - y }, defaults.rotationSpeed, function () {
                $(this).find(".picture_slide:last").after($(this).find(".picture_slide:first"));
                $(this).css({marginLeft: 0});
            })
        }, defaults.screenTime);
        $(".picture_slide").css("width", y);
        $(".slider").css("width", y * 3);       
    }
} );

$.fn[ pluginName ] = function( options ) {
    return this.each( function() {
        if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
            $.data( this, "plugin_" +
                pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
        }
    } );
};

} )( jQuery, window, document );
```

Here is the smart resize that I was told to check out:
http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

Answer (score 0):

When you're resizing the screen, you're not changing the value of `y`. This would mean that it still bears the value of the old window size, which would cause the animation to animate the incorrect amount of width.

I'd suggest making y a global vaiable and using this to recalculate the value of y when the user resizes.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    y = $(window).width();
});
```